# Number of links in the question

Tags: discussion, support, hyperlinks

How many links to the other MathSE questions may I put in my question?
Is it allowed to make with these links a context for the given question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users with less than 10 reputations points are restricted to at most two links *outside SE network*. As far as I know, there is no limit for internal links. Similarly, there is no limit on number of links once you have at least 10 reputation points.

See:

- [Privileges - New User Restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)
- [Don't limit the number of *internal* links new users can include in questions (at least on meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33184/dont-limit-the-number-of-internal-links-new-users-can-include-in-questions-a/33188#33188)

As far as the second part of your question is concerned, if your question is related to other questions on this site, then linking to them and explaining how they are related is IMO one of good ways to add context.

Comment: Well, if your question is the same as the question you are linking, then you should not be asking it. If the questions seem very similar, you should include explanation what makes your question different. You might find some information related to this in [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer) and maybe some posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108).

Comment: Ok, so it' s a matter of common sense, but sometimes it is hard to create appropriate distance metrics for the questions; what for someone is almost the same for the other is quite different.